# Creating a widget with a number of custom fields

Tags: custom-field, widgets, widget-text

I am attempting to create some custom widgets.

I have created one, which only needed a different title field. However I am now stuck when trying to create a widget which allows me to have multiple fields. I need the following fields for the widget:

- Title
- Introduction text
- Main text
- Email address

I want the widget form to allow the user to update the fields above with text. I then want to output the text they have written in my sidebar widget.

I have the following code which is for the previous widget I made (with no extra fields other than title)

```
class registercv_widget extends WP_Widget {

        function __construct() {
            parent::__construct(
                'registercv_widget',
                __('Register CV Widget', 'registercv_widget_domain'),
                array( 'description' => __( 'Provides a "Register CV" button which launches a pop-up', 'registercv_widget_domain' ), )
            );
        }

        public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
            $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] );
            echo $args['before_widget'];
            echo '<div class="widget-wrapper">';
            if ( ! empty( $title ) )
                echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];

    // This is where you run the code and display the output
            echo __( '<div class="register-button"><span><div class="button white">Send your CV</div></span></div>', 'registercv_widget_domain' );
            echo '</div>';
            echo $args['after_widget'];
        }

    // Widget Backend
        public function form( $instance ) {
            if ( isset( $instance[ 'title' ] ) ) {
                $title = $instance[ 'title' ];
            }
            else {
                $title = __( 'Register as a candidate', 'registercv_widget_domain' );
            }
    // Widget admin form
            ?>
            <p>
                <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:' ); ?></label>
                <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>" />
            </p>
        <?php
        }

    // Updating widget replacing old instances with new
        public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
            $instance = array();
            $instance['title'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['title'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] ) : '';
            return $instance;
        }
    }

    function registercv_load_widget() {
        register_widget( 'registercv_widget' );
    }
    add_action( 'widgets_init', 'registercv_load_widget' );
```

This works fine but **how can I add extra fields to this?**

I have attempted copying all instances of `$title` and making them again but with `$text_one` but I do not understand how this field is being registered. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to add more custom fields in widget back end form, for this you just need to create a new field in `form( $instance );` function.

So the code will look like

```
        // Widget Backend
        public function form( $instance ) {
            if ( isset( $instance[ 'title' ] ) ) {
                $title = $instance[ 'title' ];
            }
            else {
                $title = __( 'Register as a candidate', 'registercv_widget_domain' );
            }

            if ( isset( $instance[ 'name' ] ) ) {
                $name = $instance[ 'name' ];
            }
            else {
                $name = __( 'Enter your name', 'registercv_widget_domain' );
            }

            // Widget admin form
            ?>
            <p>
                <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:' ); ?></label>
                <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>" />
            </p>

             <p>
                <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'name' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Name:' ); ?></label>
                <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'name' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'name' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $name ); ?>" />
            </p>
        <?php
        }
```

The above code will create a new field in form. Next we will need to save/update the value of this new field in database, follow the code given below:

```
// Updating widget replacing old instances with new
    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = array();
        $instance['title'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['title'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] ) : '';

        $instance['name'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['name'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['name'] ) : '';
        return $instance;
    }
```